# How do I copy files from parent folder to sub folders using batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory, xcopy

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Eg :

1. `FolderA` contains `123.txt`.
2. `FolderB` contains `FolderB1, FolderB2, etc.`

I want to copy the files from `FolderA` to `FolderB1, FolderB2, etc.` using batch file.

Comment: Try `copy /?`, `xcopy /?`

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop to iterate over the target direcories.

```
FOR /D %%d IN (\Path\to\FolderB\*) DO copy \Path\to\FolderA\123.txt "%%~d"
```

Comment: This command is wrong. It should be: `FOR /D %%d IN (\Path\to\FolderB\*) DO copy \Path\to\FolderA\*.txt "%%~d"`. The action has to be done for each case in folder b not a

Comment: Typo: fixed. Thanks, @Monacraft. I replaced the real paths I had tested with the hypothetical \path\to\... stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
pushd "\Path\to\folderB"
for /r /d %%a in (*) do cd "%%~fa" & copy "\Path\to\FolderA\123.txt"
popd
```